# AggregateRating and ratingValue when not rated yet

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

How do I set up `AggregateRating` when the object is not rated yet (`ratingValue` = 0)?

My current setup is:

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="0" />
    <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1" />
    <div itemprop="ratingCount">0</div>
</div>
```

When I check the Microdata with the Google Testing Tool I get an error "Failed to standardize the rating value". Do I just have to set `worstRating` to 0? Or is there an other way to tell that there’s no rating yet?

Answer (score 11):

The schema specifically states that `ratingValue` is of type `text`, whilst `bestRating` and `worstRating` are `text/number`. This suggests you could put anything into `ratingValue`, even "not ranked". However, how Google would interpret that is up to debate.

However it seems to me the ACTUAL CORRECT way to implement this is to only give an `aggregateRating` where `ratingCount` > 0.

**Simply omit the ratings when there are no ratings.**

Comment: Okay thanks. When i set ratingValue to "not ranked" or "null" or when i remove the ratingValue tag i still get an error. So it seems that only setting ratingCount > 0 or setting worstRating = 0 is working "correctly". 
Removing the whole rating-thing works also :-) but i am not sure how google will rate this...

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess it does not make sense to specify a [`ratingValue`](http://schema.org/ratingValue) of `0` if the [`worstRating`](http://schema.org/worstRating) should be `1`:

- `worstRating` must be the "lowest value allowed in this rating system", which would be `0` in your case.
- A `ratingValue` of `0` does *not* mean that there are no votes yet (i.e., `0` has not a special meaning), as `0` is certainly a valid rating value (some rating systems allow this).

So either set `worstRating` to `0`, or omit `ratingValue` for items not rated yet.